# avoiding a pyinstaller .exe disapear of the screen without closing

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, pyinstaller, tkinter-canvas

I'm working on a GUI that I would like to put at the disposal for my colleagues to use under the form of .exe , after some researchs i found pyinstaller as "freezer" which work great after downloading the github version , but my issue is even if the .exe is created when i run it , it show up for less than a second on the screen and it disapears
I would like to know how to keep it on the screen (most important part) and getting it closed when the user close it himself..
Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Add this line at the end o your main python file:

```
input("Press enter to continue...")
```

This forces the cmd screen to stay open until the user hits the ENTER. I haven't found any pyinstaller native solution, but this is a good workaround

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to manually open a CMD window, navigate to, and then execute your exe, rather than letting the packaged application spawn the instance.